# Cannot get function to change pictures to work

Tags: javascript

I have updated the code to this still does not seem to work I have validates the js file is pointed correctly but when I click any option the picture refuses to update.

Here's is my code:

```js
function color() {
  if (document.getElementById('carcolor').value == 'Red') {
    document.getElementById('car_pic').src = 'image/Red.jpg';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('carcolor').value == 'Blue') {
    document.getElementById('car_pic').src = 'image/BLue.jpg';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('carcolor').value == 'Silver') {
    document.getElementById('car_pic').src = 'image/Silver.jpg';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('carcolor').value == 'White') {
    document.getElementById('ccar_pic').src = 'image/White.jpg';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('carcolor').value == 'Black') {
    document.getElementById('car_pic').src = 'image/Black.jpg';
  }
}
checkcolor();
```

```html
<div id="select1">
  <h1>Choose A Color</h1>
  <select name="color" size="5" id="carcolor">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
  <img src="" alt="car picture" id="car_pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the id of you img-element.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code :) id should not be used with space and the value is for select not for div and the {} at the last of if condition....

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems:

- `id` can't contain whitespaces
- You were using wrong `id`s in your JS
- You were attaching `id`s to the wrong elements in your html
- You were calling `checkcolor` but defined the function as `color`.
- Better avoid inline event handlers
- Avoid getting the same DOM element multiple times, better store it in a variable
- You use `if` conditionals in a wrong way.
- Instead of so many conditionals, you could use an object that gives the URL of the image given the selected value.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('select1'),
    img = document.getElementById('car_pic'),
    imgURLs = {
      Red: 'image/Red.jpg',
      Blue: 'image/Blue.jpg',
      Silver: 'image/Silver.jpg',
      White: 'image/White.jpg',
      Black: 'image/Black.jpg'
    };
function checkcolor() {
  img.src = imgURLs[sel.value];
}
sel.onchange = checkcolor;
checkcolor();
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Choose A Color</h1>
  <select name="color" size="5" id="select1">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
  <img src="" alt="car picture" id="car_pic">
</div>
```

If all image URLs follow the same pattern, consider

```js
img.src = 'image/' + sel.value + '.jpg';
```

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('select1'),
    img = document.getElementById('car_pic');
function checkcolor() {
  img.src = 'image/' + sel.value + '.jpg';
}
sel.onchange = checkcolor;
checkcolor();
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Choose A Color</h1>
  <select name="color" size="5" id="select1">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
  <img src="" alt="car picture" id="car_pic">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried what you posted above and the new edited code in my question and still it never seems to put in the desired picture any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById relates to the ID within your tag, your pointing it towards the alternative name of the the image tag. Also you assigning statements are outside your brackets;

```
if (document.getElementById('select1').value == 'Red'){} <-- Here
document.getElementById('car picture').src ='image/Red.jpg';
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById('select1').value == 'Red'){
document.getElementById('car picture').src ='image/Red.jpg';
}
```

hope it helps

Edit: Was posted after the two comments below your question, both pretty much explain it